# js Function generating href to include data-role="button"

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a JS function below that generates an href which includes the JQ Mobile data-role="button" class. This is being ignored by the browser - can anyone suggest a solution.

```
<script>  
    function showCONTACTDETAIL() {

        var tryouttext='<a href="" data-role="button">hey this is cool</a>';
        jQuery('#tryout').html(tryouttext);

        }
    $('#cusdetail').live('pageshow', function () { showCONTACTDETAIL();  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
jQuery('#tryout').html(tryouttext).trigger( "create" );
```

You need to trigger the `create` event on a container, to make all dynamic content in that container to get styled..

---

Quoting from http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/07/22/jquery-mobile-team-update-week-of-july-18th/

> Now, our handy **`create`** event will initialize all the necessary plugins
>   within that markup, just like how the page creation enhancement
>   process works. If you were to use Ajax to load in a block of HTML
>   markup (say a login form), you can trigger create to automatically
>   transform all the widgets it contains (inputs and buttons in this
>   case) into the enhanced versions.